# Alexandrov's mapping lemma

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

I'm looking for a complete proof of Alexandrov's mapping lemma. I'd also like to have the intuition for it explained if that's at all possible. Or alternatively any pointers in the right direction would also be appreciated!

Here is the statement which I found at http://www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/PolyhedraSlides.pdf

Suppose $\phi$ : A $\rightarrow$ B is a mapping between n dimensional manifolds that satisfy the following conditions:

1. Every component of B contains image points of A.
2. $\phi$ is one-to-one
3. $\phi$ is continuous
4. $\phi$ has a closed graph: if $\left\{b_{j}\right\} \subset B$ is a sequence consisting of image points $b_{j} = \phi(a_{j})$ for some $a_{j} \in A$ which converges $b_{j} \rightarrow b \in B$ as $j-> \infty$, then there exists $a \in A$ with $\phi(a) = b$ and a subsequence $a_{i_{m}}$ which converges to $a$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$

Then $\phi$ is onto, i.e., $\phi(a) = b$

Comment: Be more specific and explain what you mean by Alexandrow's mapping lemma.

Comment: OK, just provided an update for you!

Comment: This is a standard consequence of invariance of domain, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain. Namely, 4 says that  the image of $\phi$ is closed. By invariance of domain, the image of $\phi$ is also open, and hence the union of components of $B$. Now 1 implies that $\phi$ is onto.  Voting to close as not research level.

Answer (score 1):

A complete proof is given by Aleksandrov in his "Convex Polyhedra" book.

Comment: ok great, ill have a look Thanks!